# Coonection time out error comes again and again on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My code gives time out error when connecting to the database.

The strange part is that yesterday it was connecting perfectly, the same code.

look:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<MyUser>:<MyPassword>@cluster0.ot7abmk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
const client = new MongoClient(uri);


async function run(){
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
        await client.connect();
        // client.db("gastos").createCollection("gastos")
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
      }
}
```

My package.json:

```
  "name": "controle-de-gastos-full-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/G4rutti/controle-de-gastos-full-stack.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/G4rutti/controle-de-gastos-full-stack/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/G4rutti/controle-de-gastos-full-stack#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "5.0"
  }
}
```

This is the error you are getting. I personally have no idea what it is, since yesterday, the same code was working.

Error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 18.231.18.253:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (MyDir)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-02.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-00.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-01.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-hqwzt1-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 18.231.18.253:27017 closed
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-02.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-00.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-kac6ni2-shard-00-01.ot7abmk.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message there.

Comment: That looks like it got the DNS resolution for the SRV record and the individual host names, but was unable to find a primary node.  Does the cluster status in Atlas look right?

Comment: the status is active